# JAXB unmarshalling - element that appears multiple times separated by other elements

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to use JAXB to unmarshal an XML file that has an element that occurs 5 times, but not in a row; I want to make some changes, then marshal it back to XML. When written back to the XML file, the instances of the element need to go back in the same order, and be separated by the same intervening elements as before

I know I can represent an element that occurs multiple times with a Collection, and I can specify the order of fields using @XmlType( propOrder = { ... } ), but I can't figure out to do both at the same time...

I tried using 5 different field names in my Java class (encryptedData1, encryptedData2, ...), and 5 different pairs of getters/setters, and then annotating the setters with the same name:

```
@XmlElement( name = "EncryptedData" )
```

but when I unmarshal, only the first one gets set, the others are all null. The field that does get filled has the value of the last instance in the XML file, so I'm guessing it's just getting set five times

If I use a List, then when I write out to the XML file, they all get written together

Here is a sample of the original XML; the EncryptedData element is the one in question:

```
<NodeInformation>
...
  <ProxyIpPort>1194</ProxyIpPort>
  <LicenseKeyID />
  <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
    <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
    <CipherData>
      <CipherValue>************************</CipherValue>
    </CipherData>
  </EncryptedData>
  <ProxyUsername />
  <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
    <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
    <CipherData>
      <CipherValue>***********************</CipherValue>
    </CipherData>
  </EncryptedData>
  <ActualIpAddress />
  <HasMASServer>false</HasMASServer>
  <MASServerIpAddress />
  <MASServerWebListeningPort>443</MASServerWebListeningPort>
  <ModemNumber />
  <RememberLoginPassword>true</RememberLoginPassword>
  <LoginName>admin</LoginName>
  <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
    <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
    <CipherData>
      <CipherValue>***************************</CipherValue>
    </CipherData>
  </EncryptedData>
  ...
</NodeInformation>
```

Thank you in advance for any insight

Comment: The structure of your XML is not expressible in XML-Schema (the EncryptedData Element multiple times at multiple locations). Hence, it is not possible to express this using JAXB annotations. You could try to use XSLT and make your replacements, or progamatically build your document e.g. using DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you only want to change elements != EncryptedData, i.e. keep the unchanged EncryptedData elements in their relative positions?

If this is the case, it might be possible using JAXB Binder,
see [JAXB & XML Infoset Preservation](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-xml-infoset-preservation.html)

Comment: Fantastic! This worked after I switched from the default JAXB implementation to MOXy as suggested in the linked article, the only minor thing being that for some reason it strips out the value of the xmlns attribute, but I will just add it back it afterwards. Thanks for you help!